# R - how to append a data set to a list?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I append a data set into a list in R? I have this below and keeps crashing or freezing my computer when I have this line `listData <- append(listData, data1)`,

```
# Empty list for storing listData later.
listData <- list()

# Prepare SQL query1.
dataQuery <- "SELECT * ...."

# Store the result in data1.
data1 = dbGetQuery(DB, dataQuery)

if(nrow(data1) > 0) {

    # Append the data to the list.
    listData <- append(listData, data1)

}

# Merge data sets.
set.seed(1)
dataList = listData
allData = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), dataList)
```

Am I doing it wrong in R to append the data set to the list? What is the proper way of doing it then?

Answer (score 2):

Find the names of the variables that you want to put in the list:

```
dataVars <- ls(pattern = "^data[[:digit:]]+$)
```

Use `mget` to retrieve them as a list.

```
dataList <- mget(dataVars, envir = parent.frame())
```